# has no exported member 'FireListObservable'?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

I have updated firebase to the latest version 4.8.1 but after recieving errors and reading comments I have put it back to the version 4.8.0. However, I am still getting this issue.

Module '"C:/Users/oxyfi/Downloads/travel/travel/node_modules/angularfire2/database/index"' has no exported member 'FirebaseListObservable'.

I have recieved several of the same issues. Any advice would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be getting this error because you are using old Database API. This can solved by importing FirebaseListObservable from depracated module, try this import instead:

```
import {FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
```

Comment: Hi Mahesh, which folder would I add this too?

Comment: wherever you are using it right now. just change the import path

Comment: Mostly these are used in providers so import like this:  import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';

Comment: the error is in '"C:/Users/oxyfi/Downloads/travel/travel/node_modules/angularfire2/database/index"'  but I think I should change in app.module.ts or maybe app.component.ts

Comment: Yes you have to change the database import in your app.module.ts also is it like this:  import {AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';
// for auth    
import {AngularFireAuthModule} from 'angularfire2/auth';
// for database
import {AngularFireDatabaseModule} from 'angularfire2/database';

Comment: Brill thanks Mahesh I will amend the changes and get back

Comment: I have got rid of my all the errors with your line of code. I am just getting one more error now import {User} from '@firebase/auth-types'

Comment: Yes that was supposed to be used for 4.8.1 i guess for firebase 4.8.0 the import is:    import { User } from 'firebase/app';

Comment: Getting the error no provider for injectionToken Firebase App Config Token!, any idea what this is?